# How to access to a ListItem in the ListView

Tags: android

I am trying to access one of the ListItem in the ListView and it is as shown below.
A lot of people discussed for similar problem. But I tried and non of them worked.
My code is listed below.

```
 pos = 0;//position of ListItem
 for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext())
 {
     if(tel.equals(cursor.getString(2)))
         break;
     pos++;
 }  
 LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 View myView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_fragment, null);
 lvObjects = (ListView)myView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);              
 View v = lvObjects.getChildAt(pos);
```

My problems are
(1)`View v` is always `Null`.
(2)`getChildAt()` returns only visible `View`. If I want to access for the hidden `View`, how to achieve?

Comment: what`s the purpose of accessing an hidden item?

Comment: My ListView has a TextView, I need to update it when an SMS comes to update. But current problem is even in the visible View, the return is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You simply should not do this!** `ListView` does not render views it does not need to render, and it does reuse already created view objects. This is are optimizations.

Instead, supply implementation of [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) or extend one, override [`getView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method and manipulate view created by `super.getView` or created by your code.

If the `ListView` already showed the items you can make it redraw the items by calling [`ListView.invalidateViews`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#invalidateViews%28%29). It will call the adapter to draw views.

If you are using [`BaseAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) and the underlying have changed, then call [`notifyDataSetChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on the adapter.

Comment: Any sample for how to implement it.

Comment: Yeah I use ArrayAdapter. But I am in SMSReceiver, how to call notifyDataSetChanged from SMSReceiver class.

Comment: Assuming that it is not main thread, you should use `listView.post(new Runnable() { public void run() { adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); } } );`

Comment: Is what I am doing correct? Get references of ListFragment, customList_Adaptor and call Runnable. I implemented as MyListFragment newList = new MyListFragment();
             final customList_Adaptor adapter = new customList_Adaptor(context, R.layout.list_row, listIDs,activationStatus, newList);lvObjects.post(new Runnable() { public void run() { adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); } } ); But still does not update.

Comment: I think I made mistake, I should have current ListFragment, not new ListFragment.

Comment: I keep List<String> and adapter as static reference. Then update the List<String> and call lvObjects.post(new Runnable() { public void run() { MyListFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); } } );. The problem is another set of ListView are appended to the existing ListView.

Comment: Thanks, finally it works. I need to remove and add (some kind of modifications) at List<String>, then notifyDataSetChanged() update the TextView, if not it append the existing ListView.